# invoking "operator T()" in c++ smart pointer implementation

Tags: c++, templates, smart-pointers

I'm using some smart pointer implementation that contain the following operators :

```
template<class T>
class my_unique_ptr {
public:
    ...

    operator T() {
        return _t;
    }

    T *operator &() {
        return &_t;
    }

private:
    T _t;
};
```

I'm looking to get the original value from type T that wrapped by the pointer class.

The `&` operator works fine but it gives my pointer and not the value itself.

Therefore, I wish to call the `T()` operator (just like `get()` in `std::unique_ptr`)

I tried to use the variable directly, but it refers to it as `my_unique_ptr<T>` instead of `T`.

```
void func(myClass c);

int main()
{
     my_unique_ptr<myClass> x = new myClass(..);
     func(x); 
}
```

but I get error of unable cast from type 'my_unique_ptr' to pointer type 'myClass'

How can I call this operator ?

Comment: `operator->` is probably what you want

Comment: Or `operator*`.

Comment: and `T* _t;` if it's supposed to store a pointer.

Comment: You would call () operator like this: `x();`. The code does not make much sense. `_t` is not a pointer and operator () return a copy by value. And since you don't show constructor or assignement, it make it a bad question since we cannot compile it and **cannot guess what you have written** since what we have is incoherent. Look at `std::unique_prt` code if you want to learn how to write a unique pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I call this operator ?

When you use `&` on an object, that function will be called.

```
 my_unique_ptr<myClass> x = new myClass(..);
 auto ptr = &x;
```

Here, `ptr` will be of type `myClass*`. To be able use

```
 func(x);
```

You'll have to define a conversion operator.

```
operator T&() {
    return _t;
}
```

Comment: so `operator T()` is a conversion operator as well (less efficient one). but how do I call this operator. Perhaps you can add to your example code ?

Comment: @IradK, The function will be called implicitly when a conversion from `my_unique_ptr` to `T&` is required. To explicitly call it, you may use `x.operator myClass&();`

Comment: I just wonder why I got the casting error in my example If I already had this operator and according to `func` signature, it need `myClass` and not `my_unique_ptr`